# How to Change many char's combination's to one of that kind

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

In my application I want to edit string (Make many instances as one)

For example I have string:

```
string str = "/r/n/r/n/r/n Some text /r/n/r/n/r/n 45678123";
```

The wanted result:

```
"/r/n Sometext /r/n 45678123";
```

**Function like:**

```
string newStr = str.MakeToOneInstance("/r/n");
```

I need to make it dynamic (in my example I don't know how many /r/n combinations I have)

It can be any combination one more example -> `"dodo you have an answer";`

```
string newStr = str.MakeToOneInstance("do"); -> "do you have an answer";
```

I know I can make string extension Method that will use regular expression but the question if I have something like that build in .Net or maybe original way to perform that...

Comment: Do you also need to remove the space in between `Some text`?

Comment: Use a regex replace, like you have suggested

Comment: no only the specific combination

Comment: Did you mean `"\r\n"`, as in a carriage return and new line character combination?

Comment: not only /r/n its an example it can be something like "aaaaaaa loop" -> str.MakeToOneInstance("a"); ->"a loop";

Comment: Be aware that for `oooooo loop`, you'll get `o lop`...

Comment: i know gust think of that function that can be useful in some cases

Comment: something like trim(), but with parameter that will check if it have bundle and make it to one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Regex.Replace(input, @"(?:\r\n){2,}", Environment.NewLine)`

This will replace multiple occurences of `\r\n` by a single new line.

---

You can put this in an extension like so:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string MakeToOneInstance(this String str, string toReplace)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(str, string.Format("\\b(?:{0}){1}\\b", Regex.Escape(toReplace), "{2,}"), toReplace);
    }
}
```

And use it as you wanted to.

Example:

```
"oooooo loop".MakeToOneInstance("o")
"o loop"
```

Comment: I think OP wants to keep just one instance of original string, kind of: "remove all duplicates of this substring" but still this regex is the way to go (no, no built-in methods for this and without regex I'd go with `String.Split(new string[] { "/r/n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` and then `String.Join()` them again. About **edit**: shouldn't `toReplace` be escaped?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: You should make that an answer, I think it's much more suitable for the question requirements

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti yes it should, nice notice.

Comment: @musefan I'm not sure, regex (with some fixes) is much much faster and less avid of resources than creating tons of temporary strings

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: I think I would prefer to opt for your functional stability in this case, who knows what string will be fed in... of course, OP might have a fairly strict input set and it might not be a concern

Comment: Thank's. it's looks helpful

Comment: @musefan output is `"oooooo loop"`

Comment: My point is if it's any special regex sequence that needs replacing it doesn't work. For example, input: `"[x][x][x] loop"` with replace `"[x]"` (Also, I think the word boundries doesn't meet requirements, but I could be wrong)

Comment: Not exactly working (need to refactoring a little) but that's the way i though to do it (like i see there is no such functionality build in .Net framework) Thank's

Comment: @LeonBarkan feel free to add your refactored solution so others can find it easily if needed.

Comment: I will do some change's and qa it after that will post. thank's alot for quality answer.

Comment: Checked, your code works well, Thank you have some cases with problems but it's encoding stuff

Answer (score 4):

Alternative approach. May work faster than Regex if there is not too much to replace (like your example).

```
string oldStr;
do
{
   oldStr = str;
   str = str.Replace("\r\n\r\n", "\r\n");
} 
while (oldStr.Length != str.Length);
```

Edit: this approach is 10-30 times faster than Regex (tried with mono) but both are *very* fast (microseconds) so if it is not called too much I vote for regex, because it is much more readable.